# Morris.js xlabels are cut in vertical position

Tags: morris.js

I am using Morris.js

I want to add xlabels in a format of datetime (2012-02-14 12:55:00),
and I want to put them into vertical position.

But the problem is that the beginning of the text does not fit.

[image: xlabel images]

Below is my code:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element : 'graph_bar',
    data:[<?php 
    echo  $chart_data; ?>],
    xkey:  <?php echo  "'$eje_x'"; ?>,
    ykeys: [ <?php echo  "$y_keys"; ?>],
    labels: [ <?php echo  "$y_keys"; ?>],
    xLabelAngle: 90,
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `overflow` CSS property of `svg` to `visible` like this:

```
svg { overflow: visible !important; }
```

By default, this property is set to `hidden`, that's why you don't see all your labels when the height is too high.

Please try the following snippet (it seems the snippet is only working in full page):

```js
var data = [
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 11:45:00", "value": 50 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 11:55:00", "value": 5 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:05:00", "value": 10 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:15:00", "value": 30 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:25:00", "value": 84 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:35:00", "value": 43 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:45:00", "value": 23 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 12:55:00", "value": 45 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:05:00", "value": 100 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:15:00", "value": 76 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:25:00", "value": 92 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:35:00", "value": 8 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:45:00", "value": 44 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 13:55:00", "value": 77 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 14:05:00", "value": 88 },
  { "hour": "2012-02-14 14:15:00", "value": 60 }
];

Morris.Bar({
  element: 'graph_bar',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'hour',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Date'],
  parseTime: false,
  xLabelAngle: 90,
});
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="graph_bar"></div>
```

Comment: thank, you, I see that your code works correctly on stackoverflow, However I can´t apply it. I don´t know how to call "svg"

Comment: @Raimo What do you mean by _I don´t know how to call "svg"_? Morris is generating a `svg` element, so you necessarily have a `svg` element too. Did you try to add the CSS? You can try in your `head` for example: `<style>svg { overflow: visible !important; }<style>`

Comment: thank you, I needed that style tag, however my graphs are invisible, if I add the line "<style...". I have tried with my own "include" files and with your include files

Comment: you resolved my problem (I just had en external css), I try to give you feedback